# .NET 4 single application instance

Tags: .net

I often write .net applications that only support one instance. Formerly I used .net-remoting and now WCF to detect if already an instance of my app is running and giving the focus to this instance.

My question is, if there is with .net4 a better solution available to achieve single instance applications (or is there in general a better solution available, because loading the WCF or remoting assembly at the very start of the application has a bad performance influence)

**Update**

Thanks for all the post. The answer to my initial question seems to be “**no, there is nothing new to achieve single instance applications within .net 4**”.

Thanks to all the additional information, I will change my current projects to use a Mutex to provide the desired functionality.  I accepted the answer  of Bob Moore because it has the most information attached to it, but thanks to all who posted useful information.

Comment: nothing special for .net 4. wcf and remoting sound like huge overhead for such simple task

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to create a single instance application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147/what-is-the-correct-way-to-create-a-single-instance-application)

Comment: @Andrey: Yes indeed, its overhead, but I have to say that in most of theses apps I use WCF/Remoting anyway, this justifies the usage of them. But the point in time the assembly is loaded is bad because it extends the time the application takes to be loaded/initialized.

Comment: you should use mutex, as it is described in Bob Moore's answer. It is robust and fast.

Comment: @Andrey so I will do. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The traditional way to do this is with a mutex, e.g.

```
bool bNew = true; 
using (Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "MYAPP_0D36E4C9-399D-4b05-BDA3-EE059FB77E8D", out bNew))
{
   if (bNew)
   {
       // blah, blah,
       Application.Run(new MainForm());
   }
}
```

Edit:

I found this code to invoke SetForegroundWindow online, so you can find the other instance of your app and bring it forward:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);


Process me = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcessesByName (me.ProcessName))
{
   if (process.Id != me.Id)
   {
      SetForegroundWindow (process.MainWindowHandle);
      break;
   }
}
```

Note that in modern Windows implementations you can only give the foreground away.

Comment: A Mutex can be per session or machine wide.

Comment: And how to activate the existing Application (Give Focus)? PInvoke?

Comment: I believe each terminal server session has a private namespace for kernel objects. I suggest you read www.flounder.com/nomultiples.htm for a more comprehensive background. That's a native code site, but you need to understand the principles if you're venturing this far down into the innards...

Comment: I see others have pointed you at the global/local flags. Of course, it depends on what you mean by "work for terminal server". You can set it up to only allow one instance on a single physical machine, or on a single terminal.

Comment: btw, it's rather better to extract `[assembly: Guid]` value than hardcode someone

Answer (score 2):

I use a [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex(VS.71).aspx), and [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499(VS.85).aspx) to do this.

*Concerning your comment on another answer:*
For information on Local and Global mutexes in Terminal Services, [follow this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684292(v=VS.85).aspx).

> Terminal Services client processes
>   can use object names with a "Global\"
>   or "Local\" prefix to explicitly
>   create an object in the global or
>   session name space.

This is the code I use to activate the window:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool IsIconic(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
private const int SH_SHOW = 5;
private const int SH_RESTORE = 9;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

public void Activate(IntPtr hwnd)
{
    if (IsIconic(hwnd))
        ShowWindow(hwnd, SH_RESTORE);
    else
        ShowWindow(hwnd, SH_SHOW);

    SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a simpler way - with help of WindowsFormsApplicationBase class from  Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class SingleInstanceApplicationWrapper :
Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase 
{
  public SingleInstanceApplicationWrapper()
  {
    IsSingleInstance = true;
  }

  private MyApp m_app;
  protected override bool OnStartup(Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.StartupEventArgs e)
  {
    // here we create our WPF application
    m_app = new MyApp();
    m_app.Run();
    return false;
  }

  protected override void OnStartupNextInstance(Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.StartupNextInstanceEventArgs e)
  {
    m_app.DispatchCommandLineParams(e.CommandLine);
  }
}

public class MyApp : System.Windows.Application
{
  protected override void OnStartup(System.Windows.StartupEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnStartup(e);
    DispatchCommandLineParams(e.Args);
  }
  public void DispatchCommandLineParams(IEnumerable<string> cmdParams)
  {
    // process command line parameters
    Console.WriteLine(this.GetHashCode() + " - dispatched");
  }
}
public class Program
{
  [STAThread]
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    var wrapper = new SingleInstanceApplicationWrapper();
    wrapper.Run(args);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest Singleton-Pattern.
Look at this (example for VB.net!):http://vbnotebookfor.net/2007/09/13/introduction-to-the-singleton-pattern-in-vbnet/

Greetz

Comment: Sorry, I dont't understand how it helps? The singleton pattern works in the applications domain but not over different processes.