# Singleton problem in c#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What is the correct way to create a single instance application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147/what-is-the-correct-way-to-create-a-single-instance-application)
>   [What is a good pattern for using a Global Mutex in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229565/what-is-a-good-pattern-for-using-a-global-mutex-in-c)

Suppose i have created an exe i want that exe must run only once ..how it is possible please give suggestion

Comment: What do you precisely mean by "only once" - one copy at a time, once ever, or ... ?

Comment: You may take a look at [this article](http://www.ai.uga.edu/mc/SingleInstance.html).

Comment: as well as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211529/net-4-single-application-instance

Comment: See http://www.ai.uga.edu/mc/SingleInstance.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly this has nothing to do with having a singleton implementation.  You simply need to check if your executable is currently running.

You can do this by calling Process.GetProcesses() or Process.GetProcessesByName(NameOfExecutable) and checking the return values.

Alternatively use a Mutex as suggested above by others.