# Is it possible to get own process name?

Tags: c#, process

I want to replace cMyProcessName (in my example) programatic, i dont want to use a sting constant !

This is the code:

```
private const string cMyProcessName = "MyProcessName";

if (GetProcessCount(cMyProcessName) > 1)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); //Give it some time (if just restarted)
    //**************************************************************//
    if (GetProcessCount(cMyProcessName) > 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("MyProcessName is already running. Exiting.", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return;
    }
    //**************************************************************//
}

public static int GetProcessCount(string processName)
{
    Process[] ps = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);

    return ps.Length;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [prevent a c# application from running more than one instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545240/prevent-a-c-sharp-application-from-running-more-than-one-instance)

Comment: (it was not the case, i just wanted the process name)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try with this :

```
Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess();    
string cMyProcessName = p.ProcessName;
```

Comment: did you try this code? can you really assign that to a const?

Comment: Not possible... you can't have a const dynamically assigned (or it's no more a const)

Answer (score 1):

[Process.GetCurrentProcess Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getcurrentprocess.aspx) is what you need :

```
string processName = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can probably simplify your code very much by using:

```
Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
```

see here: [Process.GetCurrentProcess Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getcurrentprocess.aspx)