# Detecting whether the terminal is the modern 'Terminal' app, or the regular 'Command Prompt' in csharp

Tags: c#, terminal, console

The modern 'Terminal' app from the Windows Store supports features that the classic 'Command Prompt' application does not. I'm looking for a way to detect which my application is running in so that I can drop down the features used within the console as appropriate.

Comment: Maybe it helps to check the registry key `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\wt.exe`, its `(Default)` contains the absolute path to `wt.exe` , which is in a subdirectory of `"C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can look for the "WT_SESSION" environment variable, see [this Feature Request](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/1040).

```
if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WT_SESSION") != null)
{
    // running in Windows Terminal
}
```

Comment: This is not reliable. On my machine, "Terminal" is installed and set as default, but there is no "WT_SESSION" environment variable.

Comment: Did you check this within Terminal? More specifically: in a process started from Terminal. Only there, this Environment variable will be set.

Comment: Yes, I opened a terminal and typed `set WT_SESSION` within it. Result is: `Environment variable WT_SESSION not defined`.

Comment: Interesting. It still works fine for me on Win10 and Win11 (Terminal version: 1.18.3181.0)

Comment: Yes, same terminal version here: 1.18.3181.0, running under Win10 22H2.

Answer (score 0):

Check the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\wt.exe`, its `(Default)` contains the absolute path to `wt.exe`, which is in a subdirectory of `"C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\"`.

**Example (for LinqPad):**

```
void Main()
{
    string InstallPath = (string)Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue(
            @"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\wt.exe", 
            "", null) ?? "";
    if (InstallPath != "")
    {
        // print the absolute path to wt.exe
        InstallPath.Dump();
    }
}
```

This addresses the question whether terminal is installed or not.

To find out if the running process is a terminal, check its process name: "OpenConsole.exe" is the name of a console running in terminal.

To get its name, use this:

```
Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess();    
string cMyProcessName = p.ProcessName;
```

(as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8428224/1016343)).

Comment: This may answer the question whether or not Terminal is installed. But it does not answer the question if the current process runs in Terminal or in some other console host.

Comment: I have added a description how to get the process name.

Comment: But this will be the name of the process running *in the console* (i.e. your console app), so probably not "OpenConsole.exe" unless your console app has this name by chance.

Comment: Then the only way is to [check the list of processes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/262291/1016343) - but that does not tell you, if your application/process was actually started by `wt.exe`.