# How to stop multiple instances of my program(windows form) opening at the same time in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

My program is windows form, when built in visual studio, gives an .exe file for the form. And when this .exe file is clicked multiple times, creates multiple instances of the same form. All the programming is done in one class only. how to solve this? when the program is already open, how to stop it from opening the form again when the .exe file is clicked again?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/8fz4ssw2(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: got it, thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [prevent a c# application from running more than one instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545240/prevent-a-c-sharp-application-from-running-more-than-one-instance)

Comment: The proper way to do this is with a Mutex, not using the single instance flag. That does more than you think and I would suggest it is NEVER used.